# Can I use a plural noun before "on of the"?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

Is it correct to use a plural noun before "one of the" and in the following sentence should I use "are" or "would be"? if the sentence is incorrect please let me know the correct version.

Participating in extracurricular activities such as sport events and being a proactive student to promote my university in terms of attending conferences and meetings to talk about the features of my university **are(or would be)** one of my favorite activities.

Comment: You might also consider trimming your long, complicated sentence back or turning it into two sentences. As it stands, it's a tough read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you should not use plurals with "one of".**

Instead you could say:

> A and B are **two** of my favorite things.
>
> A and B are **some** of my favorite things.

There can be exceptions to the above rule when two or more things are treated collectively as one group. For example:

> Fish and chips is one of my favorite foods.

---

As for "are" vs "would be", that depends on your intended meaning. "Are" is the present tense, while "would be" is a conditional. If you do not need to indicate any uncertainty or hypothetical context, then simply use "are".